# Waiting for Navigation Drawer to close before initializing Fragments with empty while-loop

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

According to the [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) documentation, "Avoid performing expensive operations such as layout during animation as it can cause stuttering".

Thus, I've tried waiting for the drawer to close before proceeding:

```
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent
                                , View view
                                , int position
                                , long id) {
    // Close the drawer
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final int mPosition = position;
    Thread navThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {

            // Wait for the drawer to close
            while (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList));

            // Initialize the Fragments.
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    selectNavigationItem(mPosition);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    es.submit(navThread);
    es.shutdown();
}
```

Even though it works, Lint warns me about the empty while loop. How can I achieve this effect without the empty while-loop?

Comment: use a drawer listener.

Comment: I thought about calling `selectNavigationItem()` in `onDrawerClosed()` but I wasn't able to think of a way to allow the drawer to close if an item weren't selected.

Comment: I could use an if statement on a global boolean when an item is selected and carry around a global int for the position clicked.

Comment: i don't see how allowing the drawer to close without a selected item is relevant to your question

Comment: If the user closes the drawer without selecting an item then you simply close the drawer. If the user selects an item, the drawer needs to close and the expected action needs to occur. Thus, the `onDrawerClosed()` method (which is called anytime the drawer is closed) needs to handle both cases.

Comment: ok, understood. you could simply add the listener only when the onItemClick is called, or add a flag in onItemClick to toggle the code in the listener, like iamreptar suggests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `ListView.OnItemClickListener`:

```
@Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent
                            , View view
                            , int position
                            , long id) {
    mPosition = position;
    mNavigationItemClicked = true;
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList); 
}
```

In the `DrawerLayout`:

```
public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    if (mNavigationItemClicked)
        selectNavigationItem();
    mNavigationItemClicked = false;
}
```

In `selectNavigationItem()`:

```
switch (mPosition) {
    ...
}
```